# PGraphics camera positioning only happens in the next frame

Tags: rendering, processing

> From [this Github issue](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/4857):

*Computer specs: Mac OS Sierra 10.12.3, Processing 3.2.3*

When using dynamic values in a Processing [PGraphics](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/) camera, these only get applied in the **next** frame. I have not been able to save the current frame to a file with this offset not being a problem. Is this the expected behavior?

Consider the code below:

- It will show a rotating cube, a red rotating square, and the current frame count.
- There is an `x_up` global variable that controls that value in the camera (default 0.0).
- If the `frameCount % 90 == 0`:

  - changes the `x_up` (from 0.0 to 1.0).
  - changes the fill to transparent blue.
  - saves a file `"output/#####_" + x_up + "_.png"` (e.g: `00090_1.0_.png`)
- If the `frameCount % 90 == 1`:

  - saves another file with same convention, no fill, no `x_up` change (e.g: `00091_0.0_.png`)

```java
PGraphics pg;
PMatrix mat_scene;
float x_up;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600, P3D);
  pg = createGraphics(width, height, P3D);
  mat_scene = getMatrix();
}

void draw() {
  pg.beginDraw();
  pg.hint(DISABLE_DEPTH_TEST);
  pg.background(200);
  pg.noFill();

  // change stuff if frame % 90
  if (frameCount % 90 == 0) {
    x_up = 1.0;
    pg.fill(0, 0, 255, 10);
  } else {
    x_up = 0.0;
  }

  // the red rect
  pg.pushMatrix();
  pg.setMatrix(mat_scene);
  pg.stroke(255, 0, 0);
  pg.rectMode(CENTER);
  pg.translate(width * .5, height * .5, -600);
  pg.rotateZ(radians(float(frameCount)));
  pg.rect(0, 0, 600, 600);
  pg.popMatrix();

  // the cube
  pg.pushMatrix();
  pg.stroke(128);
  pg.translate(10, 100, -200);
  pg.rotateZ(radians(float(frameCount)));
  pg.box(300);
  pg.popMatrix();

  // the camera
  pg.beginCamera();
  pg.camera(width, height, -height, 0, 0, 0, x_up, 0.0, 1.0);
  pg.endCamera();

  // the frame counter
  pg.pushMatrix();
  pg.fill(255);
  pg.setMatrix(mat_scene);
  pg.textSize(20);
  pg.text(frameCount, 20, 30);
  pg.popMatrix();

  pg.endDraw();

  image(pg, 0, 0);

  if (frameCount > 10 && frameCount % 90 == 0) {
    saveFrame("output/#####_" + x_up + "_.png");
  }

  if (frameCount > 10 && frameCount % 90 == 1) {
    saveFrame("output/#####_" + x_up + "_.png");
  }
}
```

You can see the “blip” happen every 90 frames. If you look at the output folder, you will see something like this in frame 90:

[image]

and something like this in frame 91:

[image]

Notice that you can tell it is **only the camera** because both attributes (blue and camera x_up) are changed in frame 90 but only frame 91 shows the change in camera. Frame 90 correctly shows the blue fill in both boxes. This happens even if I set the frame rate to 1. It also happens if I use `pg.save` instead of `saveFrame`.

Is this a bug? I might be missing something obvious, but I'm not an expert in 3D transformations or cameras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the `camera()` function **after** you've done all your drawing. So each frame, you do this:

- Move the objects in your scene and take a picture.
- Now move the camera.

So on frame 90, you draw your scene, then move the camera. So on frame 91, the camera is using the position from the last frame.

To fix this, just move your call to `camera()` to **before** you draw everything (but after you set the `x_up` variable.

[image: correctly rendered scenes]